# SQL (Postgres): Bad Performance with JOIN in EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, join, select

I have three tables: `person`, `task` and a junction table `person_task`. (many-to-many relationship).
I need to select 1000 persons which have a task that is not closed. My SQL statement is as follows:

```
select p.name
from person p
where exists (
    select 1
    from person_task pt
    join task t on pt.task_id = t.id and t.state <> 'closed'
    where pt.person_id = p.id
)
limit 1000
```

What is the reason that this statement is so slow (> 3min)?
The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` generates the following result:

```
Limit  (cost=1131131.27..3469646.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=11.798..190565.952 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=1131131.27..59201135.16 rows=24832 width=8) (actual time=11.796..190565.168 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (p.id = pt.person_id)
        ->  Index Scan using personxpk on person p (cost=0.43..1384719.70 rows=2136286 width=16) (actual time=0.005..199.899 rows=1123 loops=1)
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.03..57305184.95 rows=40517669 width=8) (actual time=8.523..189657.455 rows=10451338 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..52627440.58 rows=16882362 width=8) (actual time=0.588..72881.617 rows=3484269 loops=3)
                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using person_taskx1 on person_task pt (cost=0.56..25821867.88 rows=16882362 width=16) (actual time=0.028..12726.867 rows=3484269 loops=3)
                    ->  Index Scan using taskxpk on task t (cost=0.44..1.59 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=10452808)
                          Index Cond: (id = pt.task_id)
                          Filter: (state <> 'closed')
Planning Time: 0.627 ms
Execution Time: 190566.989 ms
```

Comment: you can convert your "where clause with exist condition" into joins and then try to rerun query.

Comment: Do a VACUUM ANALYZE on all of the tables involved.  Does that change anything?

Comment: Isn't there a "Rows Removed by Filter:" line in the explain output?  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 11.9. There is no "rows removed by filter"

Comment: `VACUUM ANALYZE` did not help.. :/

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select p.name
from person p
where exists (select 1
              from person_task pt join
                   task t
                   on pt.task_id = t.id and t.state <> 'closed'
              where pt.person_id = p.id
             )
limit 1000;
```

You want the following indexes:

- `person_task(person_id, task_id)`
- `task(id, state)`

Actually, the second is not needed if `task(id)` is the primary key, which seems reasonable.

Without the first index, the subquery has to loop through a lot of data to find a particular person.  You might find this formulation faster with your existing  indexes:

```
select distinct on (p.id) p.*
from person p join
     person_task pt
     on pt.person_id = p.id join
     task t
     on t.id = pt.task_id
where t.state <> 'closed'
order by p.id;
```

Comment: I do have an index on `person_task(task_id, person_id)`. As well as  `person_task(person_id)`. The later is being used in the parallel index scan

Comment: I've tried to create an additional index on `person_task(person_id, task_id)`. But it did not help